# Integrating Simplemembership in an existing webapplication painlessly

Tags: c++, asp.net-mvc-4

Could someone please elaborate on how to implement simplemembership into an existing web application. All the blogs are very confusing and lack detail. There's one that I found that doesn't appear to work. I have an existing blog app that I've build and I'm looking for a painless way to use simplemembership..

Please help..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVC4, as you mentioned in tags:

1) Create new MVC4 Internet WebApplication

2) Copy from it:
     a)AccountController from Controllers folder
     b)AccountModels from Models folder
     c)Account folder from View folder

4) Past it to your application

5)Change everythere namesoaces to your application

6)Modify web.config:
  Add (you may copy it from new application):

```
    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="gunselEntities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="3" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership> 
   </system.web>
```

7) Add Aspnet membership tables to your database. Navigate to the wizard(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[framework version]\aspnet_regsql) and launch it. It will run special wizzard, which helps to add tables.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir.. I have it working now.. Two concerns.. First, I now have two data accesses.. UserContext and the one I built BlogContext.. I'm just forseeing upcoming issues.. Also.. How do you access the data in the view.. (ie) I'm attempting to build a User management page and would like to pass the UserId to the controller to query the specific user.. But thank you for your help again.. Very much appreciated.

Comment: To iterate on what I'm asking.. Im trying to pass the UserId through a Html.ActionLink helper attribute { id=@User.UserId }.. I cant access the data because the model is set up with several subclasses..

Comment: @digiShadoe Better pass username instead UserId. It easealy may be get by User.Identity.Name request. As to UserId, you need to lines to access it. First get user: var user = Membership.GetUser(); Second get userID: Guid currentUserID = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey

Comment: @Andrey... Did I vote up correctly? Please let me know... Your answered helped tremendously..